# How to make a bit select chip in HDL?

Tags: hdl, nand2tetris

**BitSelect** chip has: 3-bit input and 8-bit output.

```
CHIP BitSelect
{
    IN bit[3];
    OUT out[8];

    PARTS:
    // what parts to use?

}
```

How to achieve behaviour described by the truth table below?

```
in          out
000.      00000001
001.      00000010
010.      00000100
011.      00001000
100.      00010000
101.      00100000
110.      01000000
111.      10000000
```

Answer (score 0):

The chip that matches you description is called a *demultiplexor*.
`DMux8Way` built in project 01 of the course is almost the same:

```
/**
 * 8-way demultiplexor:
 * {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} = {in, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} if sel == 000
 *                            {0, in, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} if sel == 001
 *                            etc.
 *                            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, in} if sel == 111
 */
```

It has 2 inputs:

```
IN in, sel[3];
```

and 8 outputs:

```
 OUT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
```

You now have to adjust it a little to be it the only part that you need:

1) `in` to `DMux8Way` has to be always **1** (or true in HDL)  as you need to switch where **1** goes.

2) instead of 8 single outputs a..h you have to wire them to make a single 8-bit output out[8] that matches your chip's requirements

If you need to create your chip from more basic parts it's a whole different story but still should give you pretty good idea what to do and what to look for in your design.
As I treat this quesion as "homework help" whether it's actual homework or not I don't give you the copy-paste solution but this should help you keep going into right direction. 
If you need further help you always can edit your question with more specific questions or ask new one if the topic differs much from original one.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using logic gates, for example, `111` would be `bit[0]` and `bit[1]`, which is then anded together with `bit[2]`

Please don’t plagiarize any work or I’ll set Muller on you.